# getting Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: cannot dereference scalar collection element: roles

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have this class , and i'am trying to acess `mobileNumbers` and `roles` from the user table , but being `lazy` intialized i keep getting `'lazy intialization error`.

I do not wan't to remove the `LAZY` fetch as complete access of the object is rarely required , but is required. So to overcome it first i tried to add `@Transactional` but going by this  article https://codete.com/blog/5-common-spring-transactional-pitfalls/ it seems a bad approch in my case, i tried using `join fetch` but it keeps giving `multiplebagfetchexception` ,hence i tried to fetch them one at a time ( Element Collections i mean)

with this repository class

```
public interface UserRespository extends JpaRepository<UserDao, Long> {

    Optional<UserDao> getByUserNameIgnoreCase(String userName);
//    Optional<UserDao> findByUserNameIgnoreCase(String userName);

    @Query(value = "select dao.roles.roles from UserDao dao inner join dao.roles r on dao.userName in elements(r.userName) and upper(dao.userName) = upper(?1)")
    Object getByUserNameIgnoreCaseComplete2(String userName);
}
```

then i get his error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: cannot dereference scalar collection element: roles
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.ElementPropertyMapping.toType(ElementPropertyMapping.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.toType(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1644) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:396) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:515) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:682) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolveSelectExpression(DotNode.java:744) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolveSelectExpression(HqlSqlWalker.java:1057) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2295) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2232) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1503) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    ... 112 common frames omitted
```

I'm not sure why i keep getting this error.Is there any other way i can get the entire object??

Please help.

**The actual class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserDao implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "user_name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = java.lang.String.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "mobile_numbers_List",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_name",referencedColumnName = "user_name"))
    @Column(name = "mobile_number")
    private List<String> mobileNumbers;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = java.lang.String.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "roles_list",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_name",referencedColumnName = "user_name"))
    @Column(name = "roles")
    private List<String> roles;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a similar question you [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62915782/spring-jpa-how-to-only-fetch-embeddedcollection-only) , and the answer to the previous one and this one is same.

your query is wrong here

```
    @Query(value = "select dao.roles.roles from UserDao dao inner join dao.roles r on dao.userName in elements(r.userName) and upper(dao.userName) = upper(?1)")
    Object getByUserNameIgnoreCaseComplete2(String userName);
```

it's trying to fetch `dao.roles.roles` which if does not even exist.

here are some changes you should try

1. change `dao.roles.roles` to r (as you already created an alias , let's use it)
2. remove `dao.userName in elements(r.userName)` it's not required, spring does this automatically without even specifying it.
3. change the return type to list , it's `ElementCollection` i.e **Collection** of elements

this is how your final query would look like

```
    @Query(value = "select r from UserDao dao inner join dao.roles r on upper(dao.userName) = upper(?1)")
    List<String> getByUserNameIgnoreCaseComplete2(String userName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did u comment out `findByUserNameIgnoreCase` ? `findBy` Worked for me
[Take a peek in this page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

Comment: because it is not what i want currently , also that was throwing 'LazyIntializationException' which is expected when i'am having a fetch type as 'lazy' here is link to read more on it https://thorben-janssen.com/lazyinitializationexception/

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is the `dao.roles.roles` in your query. Change it to `dao.roles`.
`dao.roles` in your case is a `List<String>` and a `String` does not have a property `roles`.

Comment: getting this `Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: not an entity`