# Hibernate query exception:cannot dereference scalar collection element

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate

I am getting following error after starting my spring application:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: cannot dereference scalar collection element: metadata_descriptor_id [SELECT d FROM com.org.entity.documents.Document d INNER JOIN d.documentMetadata md ON md.document_id = d.id WHERE (md.metadata_descriptor_id.id NOT IN (:documentMetadataId))]
```

**Here is my Document class**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "documents")
public class Document {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String name;

@Column(name = "archived", nullable = false)
private boolean archived;

@Column(name = "creation_date", nullable = false)
private Instant creationDate;

@Column(name = "file_text_processing_status", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private FileTextProcessingStatus fileTextProcessingStatus;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "template_file_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private TemplateFile templateFile;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "state_descriptor_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private StateDescriptor stateDescriptor;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private UserEntity user;

@ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
@Column(name = "tag", nullable = false)
@CollectionTable(name = "document_tags", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "document_id"))
private Set<String> tags = new HashSet<>();

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "document_metadata", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "document_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "metadata_descriptor_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@Column(name = "value", nullable = false)
private Map<MetadataDescriptor, String> documentMetadata = new HashMap<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "document", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<DocumentFileVersion> documentVersions = new HashSet<>();`enter code here`
```

**And here is Repository method that fails**:

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@Query(value = "SELECT d FROM Document d INNER JOIN d.documentMetadata md ON md.document_id = d.id"
                + " WHERE (md.metadata_descriptor_id NOT IN (:documentMetadataId))")
List<Document> findAllByDocumentRequiredMetadataNotSet(long documentMetadataId);
```

I have seen an answer for similar question here: [getting Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: cannot dereference scalar collection element: roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63053808/getting-caused-by-org-hibernate-queryexception-cannot-dereference-scalar-colle)

But it's not helpful in my case. I will be very glad for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `md` is `String` this is why you see an error. What you need is something like this:

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@Query(value = "SELECT d FROM Document d INNER JOIN d.documentMetadata md WHERE (KEY(md).id NOT IN (:documentMetadataId))")
List<Document> findAllByDocumentRequiredMetadataNotSet(long documentMetadataId);
```

You also had a ON clause which is no necessary/wrong. I think you should read into HQL/JPQL first as you don't seem to understand that a join of an association, will add the join predicate in the SQL automatically.

Note though, that the syntax `KEY(..).id` is only supported in newer Hibernate versions, so you might have to update.